# Obtain specific geometry type when connecting to WFS through Arcgis Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geometry, wfs

I connect to the WFS and I successfully receive Polygons, as this seems to be the first geometry type it creates, but this WFS also has lines and points. How to specify the type of geometry I want to create as a layer. In QGIS i can specify geometryType = 'Point' in the WFS settings, but I cannot seem to find this option on Arcgis Pro (3.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Clip from WFS connection popup]

Okay, I managed to find a solution. In the WFS connection settings open the custom request parameter, add the cql_filter option and it should work.